# How can I remove the "glowing" feature from objects? It is causing CS:GO to lag

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, ubuntu

Today when playing Nuke I noticed places such as '*T Roof*' and '*vent*' being 'shiny':

[image: Screenshot showing the glowing effect on models in the game]

Before today they didn't look like that. I haven't made any changes to video settings (they are all set to low).
How can I remove this feature and make them look normal again?

The reason why I'm asking this is because CS:GO is lagging a lot. I never had this issue before, but now the FPS is ~30, even though my ping is 5. The FPS drops especially when I have more than one other player close to me.

The CPU usage for the game shows > 100%, which is really weird, because I have explicitly adjusted the launch options to use more than one core, using `-threads 8`. My CPU model is Intel Core i7-8550U.

Why is this happening?

This is what my 'top' looks like in a competitive game in Nuke, playing with bots:

[image]

Comment: I would have a look at your graphic settings and confirm everything is at their lowest setting and then confirm that you're still having this issue.

Comment: @Matthew, yes everything is at their lowest.

Comment: @Matthew I updated the question. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: To me, this looks like a bloom/graphic option - it may even be that the lowest settings are what is causing this. Perhaps a full uninstall of the game and re-install with all data removed and seeing what the result is.

Comment: @Matthew I already did that, and I get the same result

Comment: You may want to add GPU details to your question.  It might not be powerful enough anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I opened a ticket with Steam Support, and this was their response:

> Hello,
>
> Based on your machine's specs you may experience performance and/or
>   launch issues when playing CS:GO that are difficult to provide
>   adequate support for. We have recently seen an increase in reports
>   from users with Intel integrated GPUs with similar issues and we are
>   collecting this feedback and passing it on to the CS:GO devs so they
>   can investigate. Please be advised that developer access to a wide
>   variety of system configurations for testing has been severely
>   impacted by COVID-19. While the CS:GO devs are investigating please
>   keep an eye on the CS:GO blog for updates regarding this issue.
>
> For now we recommend reading our Troubleshooting Game Performance
>   Issues article for general information on improving your machine's
>   performance while playing the game. If the article does not help we
>   are limited in the support we can provide due to the number of unique
>   configurations and settings our users have.
>
> CS:GO remains in constant development. As new features are added and
>   improvements are made to graphical fidelity and sound, the game's
>   practical system requirements will continue to increase. Because of
>   this, troubleshooting issues on machines at or near system
>   requirements is difficult without having physical access to your
>   machine for various testing and troubleshooting.
>
> Because we have provided all the information we have regarding this
>   issue I'm closing this help request. I'm sorry we don't have a fix
>   right now and we appreciate your patience while we look into this.
>
> Jumping through portals, Noki

My GPU is indeed Intel, so I just have to wait for the fix.

Answer (score 5):

The [March 27th update](https://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/2020/03/29271/) implemented the following changes:

> - **Refactored low level shaders** to fix stuttering on NVIDIA hardware when first rendering previously unseen content.
> - **Speculative fix** for rare crash at the end of matches.

Valve employer vMcJohn on Reddit [said](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/fpnzpk/counterstrike_global_offensive_prerelease_update/) that regarding the update they "*changed how certain low level shaders work for all users.*"
A commentator reacted: "*while playing, I checked my video settings and it appeared that nothing was different - but my game looked entirely different. Almost like it went on a higher graphic setting. I'm assuming it has to do with the low level shaders you mentioned.*"
Since 'speculative fixes' have been rolled out in more updates lately, I think the 'refactored low level shaders' might be the culprit here.

[More people](https://www.hltv.org/forums/threads/2269268/csgo-new-update-bug) [are complaining](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/fqksuq/cs_go_update_2732020_fps_issue/), and the problem doesn't just hit people with low specs or without dedicated GPUs.

You could try [opting in to beta updates](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9847-WHXC-7326) for CS:GO in order to receive bug fixes sooner, or lower other video settings (like the resolution).
Other than that - **since you can't turn off post-processing - it seems there is little you can do.**

Comment: Hi, I upvoted and awarded you the bounty, but I have to accept my own answer, since it has direct information from Steam Support.