# CS:GO does not run using dedicated GPU

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, windows-10, graphics-card

I have a HP Omen 15 laptop and it has an i7-8700HQ CPU and GTX 1050 Ti. It used to run 140-160 fps, but at some point it started to run at 40-80 fps. Monitor refresh rate is 144hz.

Before you say "CSGO is CPU heavy", watch this:

.

I set CSGO to use NVIDIA on the NVIDIA Control Panel, Windows graphics setting, and run it using GeForce Experience, but it didn't work.

[image]

So I disabled UHD altogether and it says 140-160 fps.

[image]

But I noticed it wasn't as fast as it used to be. It turns out when I go to Windows advanced display settings, the only option is 64hz. But when I enabled UHD the option is 60hz and 144hz. Only CSGO has this problem, other games are fine.

I tried to change it from the BIOS, from MSHybrid to dedicated. But HP have locked the advanced settings.

I hoped somebody reading this has other solutions, before I nuke Windows, flash BIOS, and regret doing those because it didn't help.

*Or other fixes e.g. does anyone know an app to switch from MSHybrid to dedicated? Or how to fix the display so it can run at 144hz again?

Comment: Check your temps. If they get too high you lose performance.

Comment: I get the feeling nuking Windows won't solve the problem. Since the problem only affects CSGO, it could instead be a recent update to either the game or the graphics drivers.

Comment: i forgot to mention, i tried installing many older nvidia driver, and i used ddu to uninstall, didnt solve the problem, i even tried switching from dch to standart and vice versa. and no, it isnt thermal throthling

Comment: Also no update to the game itself, then? We've had [a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/367012/) recently about a sudden drop in frames because of a shader 'fix'.

Comment: @Joachim i dont know exactly where it went wrong, its either windows or csgo, i dont think its intel or nvidia at fault. and as you see the problem is that its using the UHD rather then GTX

Comment: You have to go to Nvidia Control Panel and set the game to use dedicated GPU. You can also toggle High Performance mode from there.

Comment: @LittleHelper i already set csgo to use dedicated gpu from nvidia control panel and windows setting "i set csgo to use nvidia on the nvidia control panel, windows graphic setting, and run it using geforce experience"